# dictionary with multiple values per key python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I have one dataframe -

```
ID T Q1 P Q2
10 xy 1 pq 2
20 yz 1 rs 1
20 ab 1 tu 2
30 cd 2 cu 2
30 xy 1 mu 1
30 bb 1 bc 1
```

Now I need a dictionary with Id as key and rest of the column values as a list to be the dictionary's value

**output**:

```
{10:['xy',1,'pq',2]}
{20:['ab',1,'tu',2]}
{30:['bb',1,'bc',1]}
```

**Expected result**:

```
{10:[['xy',1,'pq',2]]}
{20:[['yz',1,'rs',1],['ab',1,'tu',2]]}
{30:[['cd',2,'cu',2],['xy',1,'mu',1],['bb',1,'bc',1]]}
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: I am getting the output and I want the expected result, do you know something about it?

Comment: Yes, use a nested list instead of a flat list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby("ID")
    .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:, 1:].agg(list).values.tolist())
    .to_dict()
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```py
{10: [['xy', 1, 'pq', 2]], 
 20: [['yz', 1, 'rs', 1], ['ab', 1, 'tu', 2]], 
 30: [['cd', 2, 'cu', 2], ['xy', 1, 'mu', 1], ['bb', 1, 'bc', 1]]}
```